# VBA Word change all borders if every cell in a table

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to make the same table over and over again so I would like to create a table using a VBA macro.

So far I have succeeded in creating the table and changing the widths of the cells. 
Now I want to set every border in the table to wdLineStyleNone.

How would I be able to do this.

This is the code I have made so far.

```
Sub tabel_maken()
'
' tabel_maken Macro
'
'
    ActiveDocument.Tables.Add Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=4, NumColumns:= _
        2, DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:= _
        wdAutoFitFixed
    With Selection.Tables(1)
        If .Style <> "Tabelraster" Then
            .Style = "Tabelraster"
        End If
        .ApplyStyleHeadingRows = True
        .ApplyStyleLastRow = False
        .ApplyStyleFirstColumn = True
        .ApplyStyleLastColumn = False
        .ApplyStyleRowBands = True
        .ApplyStyleColumnBands = False
    End With
    Selection.Tables(1).Rows.SetLeftIndent LeftIndent:=3.75, RulerStyle:= _
        wdAdjustNone
    Selection.Tables(1).Columns(1).SetWidth ColumnWidth:=63.8, RulerStyle:= _
        wdAdjustNone
    Selection.Tables(1).Columns(2).SetWidth ColumnWidth:=297.7, RulerStyle:= _
        wdAdjustNone
    Selection.Tables(1).Range.Select
    Selection.Borders(wdBorderTop).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
    Selection.Borders(wdBorderLeft).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
    Selection.Borders(wdBorderBottom).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
    Selection.Borders(wdBorderRight).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
    Selection.Borders(wdBorderDiagonalDown).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
    Selection.Borders(wdBorderDiagonalUp).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
    Selection.Borders(wdBorderTop).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
    Selection.Borders(wdBorderLeft).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
    Selection.Cells.Borders(wdBorderLeft) = wdLineStyleNone


End Sub
```

I guess I am looking for something to change the inner borders of a table.

When I leave `Selections.Tables(1).Range.Select` out only the first cell is selected. 
When I leave this code in, then the outside border of the table is selected.

In the end I tried to select all cells and change the borders that way, but that didn't work either. `Selection.Cells.Borders(wdBorderLeft) = wdLineStyleNone)`

I hope someone can help me with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just the check the lines below for your requirement

```
 Set myTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    With myTable.Borders

' Inner lines

    .InsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleNone

' Outer lines
     .OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
    End With
```

Comment: I changed `ActiveDocument.Tables(1)` to `Selection.Tables(1)` Then it worked.